Progress bar but marker on top of the bar
Tried a lot of things including calculations but I cannot recreate this mockup. I was able to do this but the marker is inline the bar, and using
Is this possible in CSS? Or are there other approaches you could suggest? This is a part of an HTML report so the figures will not dynamically change. But on the rendering of the report, the marker should move the progress bar and follow the color of the gradient it is on.

This is what I currently have.


<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    /* Container styling */
    
    .progress-container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 10px;
    }
    /* Progress bar container */
    
    .progress-bar {
      position: relative;
      height: 10px;
      width: 300px;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff00ff, #00f0ff, #00ff99);
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    /* Progress fill */
    
    .progress {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: transparent;
      /* No color needed as the full gradient is in the parent */
      z-index: 1;
    }
    /* Marker styling */
    
    .marker {
      position: absolute;
      top: -6px;
      /* Adjust to lift it above the bar */
      right: -7px;
      /* Positions at the end of the progress */
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
      background: inherit;
      /* Inherit the gradient color */
      border-radius: 50%;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      z-index: 2;
      /* Ensures the marker is above the progress bar */
    }
    /* Text styling */
    
    .progress-text {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress-bar">
      <div class="progress" style="width: 15%;">
        <div class="marker"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-text">15%</div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>




To match the backgrounds, they should have the same size to get similar gradients, then for the dot, an offset position equals to the progress value will set it on the right position.
For the rounded effect , an svg set as a filter could do.
You can easily update the progress value & background-position at once  through a CSS var() . CSS var cannot be applied via content, so that part has to be written. If those value come from your backend, then set the values and text from there.


body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.progress-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  filter: url('#goo')
}


/* init */

.progress-text::after {
  content: '15%';
}

.progress-bar {
  --percent: 15%;
}


/* end init */

.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff00ff, #00f0ff, #00ff99);
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/* Progress fill */

.progress {
  width: var(--percent);
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  /* No color needed as the full gradient is in the parent */
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Marker styling */

.marker {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  /* Adjust to lift it above the bar */
  right: -7px;
  /* Positions at the end of the progress */
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff00ff, #00f0ff, #00ff99) var(--percent);
  background-size: 300px auto;
  /* Inherit the gradient color */
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  /* Ensures the marker is above the progress bar */
}


/* Text styling */

.progress-text {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
<div class="progress-container">
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="marker"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-text"></div>
  <!-- svg filter -->
  <svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="4" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 20 -8" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
</div>



Snippet with a bit of javascript for the demo to modify % value


let textperc =document.querySelector('.progress-text');
let progress =document.querySelector('.progress-bar');
let iptpercent = document.querySelector('#percent');
iptpercent.addEventListener("change", function(){
  textperc.textContent= this.value+'%';
  progress.style.setProperty('--percent', this.value+'%')
})
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.progress-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  filter: url('#goo')
}


/* init */
.progress-text::after {
  /*content: '15%';*//* removed, js takes care of it in this demo */
}

.progress-bar {
  --percent: 15%;
}


/* end init */

.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff00ff, #00f0ff, #00ff99);
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/* Progress fill */

.progress {
  width: var(--percent);
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  /* No color needed as the full gradient is in the parent */
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Marker styling */

.marker {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  /* Adjust to lift it above the bar */
  right: -7px;
  /* Positions at the end of the progress */
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff00ff, #00f0ff, #00ff99) var(--percent);
  background-size: 300px auto;
  /* Inherit the gradient color */
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  /* Ensures the marker is above the progress bar */
}


/* Text styling */

.progress-text {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* demo purpose */

html {
  min-height:100vh;
  display:grid;
  place-content:center
}
<input id="percent" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="15">%
<div class="progress-container">
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="marker"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-text">15%</div>
  <!-- svg filter -->
  <svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="4" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 20 -8" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
</div>



You may take a look at https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/ about the svg filter applied via filter

Thanks @G-Cyrillus. I really appreciate it. This is awesome! Saved me a couple more hours.
